# MongoDB C# Driver Projection and Serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have got a working code to join two mongo collections using $lookup.

```
        [HttpGet("mongojoin")]
        public IActionResult GetMongoJoinCollection([FromQuery(Name = "schoolId")] Guid schoolId)
        {
            var tabAssessmentCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TabAssessmentDocument>(MongoSettings.TabAssessmentDocumentName);
            var tabComponentCollection =
                mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TabComponentDocument>(MongoSettings.TabComponentDocumentName);                   
            
            var resultMongo = tabAssessmentCollection
                .Aggregate()
                .Match(d => d.SchoolId.Equals(schoolId))
                .Lookup(
                    foreignCollection: tabComponentCollection,
                    localField: ta => ta.ComponentId,
                    foreignField: tc => tc.TblId,
                    @as: (TabAssessmentDocument ta) => ta.Component
                )
                .Unwind(d => d.Component)
                .ToList();

            var resultList = new List<TabSubjectDocumentViewModel>();
            
            foreach (var row in resultMongo)
            {
                resultList.Add(new TabSubjectDocumentViewModel()
                {
                    Id = row["TblId"].AsGuid,
                    SchoolId = row["SchoolId"].AsGuid,
                    Name = row["Name"].AsString,
                    ShortName = row["ShortName"].AsString,
                    Active = row["Active"].AsNullableBoolean,
                    TabComponent = row["Component"]["Name"].AsString
                });
            }
            
            return Ok(resultList);
        }
    }

public class TabSubjectDocumentViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public string TabComponent { get; set; }
}

public class TabAssessmentDocument
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TblId { get; set; }
    public Guid? SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public Guid? ComponentId { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}

public class TabComponentDocument
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TblId { get; set; }
    public Guid? SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string ComponentType { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using the Project method just after the .Unwind(d => d.Component), but, then I was not getting the $lookup collection data (TabComponent) in the Bsondocument. If I could Serialize this to a List, how should I be doing it ? Can anyone tell me how I should using the Projection and Serialization here ?

Comment: as far as I can see your code can't be complied, please check it

Comment: @dododo This is not a whole project, I only have the necessary pieces of code - it does compile and I got the output for the web api endpoint.

Comment: i'm saying about your linq query. `TabAssessmentDocument` doesn't have a Component field. So your linq query itself doesn't compile